# AT commands USSD reply HEX

Tags: at-command

AT commands USSD reply for

`AT+CUSD=1,"*2#",15` is

`+CUSD: 0,"004D00530049005300440038003300360033",72`

But I need this reply with plain text like "Your balance is 27"

My modem is `ZTE 190`.

Answer (score 1):

your USSD reply is equivalent to "MSISD8363"

you can convert using this C# methods:

```
    public static byte[] StringToByteArray(string hex)
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(0, hex.Length)
            .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
            .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(x, 2), 16))
            .ToArray();
    }

    private void ExecuteHex2Unicode()
    {
        var k = StringToByteArray(MessageBody);
        MessageBox.Show(Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetString(k));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Split only double quotation area

```
       Like: string hexString = "0059006F007500720020006100630063006F0075006E0074002000620061006C0061006E00630065002000690073002000420044005400200030002E00300030002000560061006C00690064002000740069006C006C002000300032002D00300038002D0032003000320030003B";
```

//your splitted area

```
        byte[] bytes = StringToByteArray(hexString);
        var strArray = (Encoding.Default.GetString(
             bytes,
             0,
             bytes.Length - 1)).Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\r", "\n", "\0" },
                                         StringSplitOptions.None);
        string str = string.Join("", strArray);
```

StringToByteArray method like this:

```
public static byte[] StringToByteArray(string hex)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(0, hex.Length)
        .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
        .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(x, 2), 16))
        .ToArray();
}
```